# REST Java client API: Release connection before allocating another

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm calling a REST service using this test code:

```
public class TestRESTServices {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/ma.ge.persistence-1.0/rest/reference";
    private static URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(BASE_URL).port(8080).build();
    private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    @Test
    public void createAndDeleteAReference() {

        Reference r = ReferenceFactory.createReference("Maz",
                "dummy", 1.7);
        Response response = client.target(uri).request().post(Entity.entity(r, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        assertEquals(Response.Status.CREATED, response.getStatusInfo());

        URI referenceURI = response.getLocation();

        // Get the posted reference
        response = client.target(referenceURI).request().get();

        Reference retreivedRef = response.readEntity(Reference.class);
        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK, response.getStatusInfo());
        assertEquals(retreivedRef.getName(), r.getName());

    }
```

But I get the following error:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:159)
>       at ma.gesto.persistence.TestRESTServices.createAndDeleteAReference(TestRESTServices.java:34)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
>   Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:162)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:139)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:456)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
>       ... 26 more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Client` interface represents external resources. As such, it is a critical mistake to create and store one in a static variable. This is wrong:

```
private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

This is ok for unit testing:

```
private Client client;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    this.client.close();
}
```

In normal code you would want to wrap `Client` usage in a `try-with-resources` or `try..finally`:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
try {
    // use the client to make requests
} finally {
    client.close();
}
```

Ideally there would be a way to manage a pool of `Client` instances for reuse.

Comment: But the docs of Client contains: "Clients are heavy-weight objects that manage the client-side 
 communication infrastructure. Initialization as well as disposal of a Client instance may be a rather 
 expensive operation. It is therefore advised to construct only a small number of Client instances in the 
 application."

Comment: @snorbi Yes, which is why you would ideally want them to be managed in a pool of reusable Client instances, as per the last sentence of my answer. The pool allocation logic would detect disconnected Client instances (commonly by intercepting exceptions) and replace them with fresh ones. Two design patterns come to mind as particularly applicable to resource pools: [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to close your **Response** to free up the connection.
See explanations here:
[Resteasy Client keeping connection allocated after a method throws an Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343005/resteasy-client-keeping-connection-allocated-after-a-method-throws-an-exception/45463985#45463985)